# Contrast Hol Hamo'ed Torah readings for Pesach vs. Hol Hamo'ed Succot

Tags: passover, torah-reading, sukkot, chol-hamoed

I realize that the sacrifice for each day of Succot was different, whereas on Pesach they were the same for all days of Pesach. Somehow, this affects the Torah reading during Hol Hamo'ed.

For purposes of this example, I will use what occurs in Israel during Hol Hamo'ed Succot. There, each day of Hol Hamo'ed, they read the sacrificial offering for that day 4 times - the same thing for each of the 4 aliyot.

During Hol Hamo'ed Pesach, both in Israel and outside, each day of Pesach gets a unique separate reading (for the 1st 3 aliyot) that is not related to the sacrifice.

Why is Pesach different from Succot? OK, so the sacrifice of each day is the same. So, why don't we just read the part about the sacrifice for all 4 aliyot, and just have the same reading for all of Hol Hamo'ed Pesach? Is there some rule that says that each day's reading must be different? (Seems not - in Diaspora, the 1st and 2nd day Succot Torah readings are identical!)

Comment: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jR9qpa--pqIJ:www.biu.ac.il/JH/Parasha/pesah/marzbach.doc+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: Also readings for the first and second day of Rosh Chodesh are identical, even in Israel.