# Difference in Torah readings Israel vs. Diaspora and Pesach vs. Succot

Tags: passover, eretz-yisrael, torah-reading, chutz-laaretz, sukkot

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56478/5275) has a link in one of the comments referring to an article explaining why each day of Pesach has a different Torah reading.

During Succot, I notice that the 2nd day of Yom Tov in Diaspora repeats the reading of the 1st day, whereas in Israel, the reading is different, and is only from the Succot sacrificial offerings mentioned in parshat Pinchas. I assume that in Diaspora, the reason we repeat the 1st day's reading is respect to Yom Tov, as we treat the 2nd day as the first? Technically, what would be wrong with reading the sacrificial portions as they do in Israel. and just repeating the readings of some sections, if needed. (We do this, anyway, on all days of Hol Hamo'ed Succot.)

Another way is to view this in "reverse". On the 2nd day of Pesach, we could repeat the reading of the 1st day in Diaspora. Yet, here, Israel and Diaspora have the same reading, except for the number of aliyot, where Diaspora has 5 and Israel has 4.

Why the difference in the reading rules between Pesach and Succot?

Answer (score 0):

If the 2nd day of Pesach has a "doubt" as to whether it is the first or second day then we would probably read both that of the first day and that of the second which means we would have to remove 3 Sifrei Torah instead of 2, and would have to do the same every day except the 8th day.

On Sukkot it is less of a problem as the 2nd day reading is Maftir only and is adjacent to the one we read on the 1st day so we just read both in the diaspora.

On Chol Hamoed Sukkot outside Israel we read 3 different portions then for the 4th aliyah repeat 2 of the days, the ones we are "not sure" it might be.

With regards to Pesach though, there is also an aspect that we do "know what day it is" (e.g. the Omer counting and Chadash observance) and we keep the 2nd day as Yom Tov as a "long-kept minhag" so we combine those aspects by reading the associated 2nd day Torah reading on the day we observe as the 2nd day, even though that day is Chol Hamoed in Israel. We split it into 5 aliyos instead of 4.

Note when it comes to the extra day of Yom Tov, (acharon) we do NOT repeat the k'ryia from the previous day but read instead the portion in Devarim (R'eh) about festivals. Thus we do not repeat "Shira" on 8th day nor the 10 commandments on 2nd day Shavout. And for Shmini Atzeret we actually postpone it to the extra day to read that portion.

Therefore, in general, although we keep an extra day as Yom Tov we do differentiate between the days with regards to what we read from the Torah, as has been our tradition.